# How do I align an item to the right inside a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm starting to use flex box but not sure how I set an element inside a flex container to be positioned on the right side? I've tried applying `align-self: flex-end` and `justify-content: flex-end` with no success so I'm hoping someone can help me out?

**CSS**

```
.ctn {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: navy;
  background: lightyellow;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/styler/pen/pvJFA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The align-self property is similar to the align-items property:  it only changes its alignment on the cross axis (that's vertically when you're using the row direction).  Not what you want here.

You can use the justify-content property.  If you have more than 2 items, they will be evenly spaced out with the first item all the way to the left and the last item all the way to the right:

```
.ctn {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Or you can use margin-left on the item you want to shift all the way to the right.  If you have more than 2 items, it will shift all of the preceding items all the way to the left:

```
.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: navy;
  background: lightyellow;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` was the fix for me. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your Flexbox Cheatsheet: 
[Complete Guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

And you can use this handy tool too : [FLEXY](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

**UPDATE: As for OP pointed out in comments that this dosen't exactly solves the problem , so here's the jsfiddle:** [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BC6zP/) . Do tell me if posting a code that solves browser-inconsistency ( FYI , there are 3 seperate versions of Flex : [versions](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/) ) interferes with your exisiting solution.

Now for your question ,here is a sample code :

```
.ctn {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -moz-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.btn{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

/*
    Legacy Firefox implementation treats all flex containers
    as inline-block elements.
*/

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .ctn {
      width: 100%;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help with my question? I really only want to know how to align an individual element to the right of the flex container? Like flex: 1 1 auto; will take up all remaining space and this isn't what I want.

Comment: @styler Have you even tried this? I provided you a portion of code considering general requirements for your question. I don't even know why the downvotes! And you are free to remove any code you want from the example , i just wanted to cover every property of flex box. I have modified for your convenience, do take a look.

Comment: Apologies, I just felt it never really answered my question. My codepen uses auto-prefix so I don't need to worry about adding in those prefixes. Nowhere in the code does it actually tell me how to position the 2 elements inside the flex wrapper. I've retracted the downvote. Sorry again.